# Why does an error pop up after trying to append?

Tags: lua, lua-table, metatable

```
table1 = {1,2,3,4,5}
table2 = {1,2,3,4}
metatable ={__add = function(table,otherTable)
    sumTable = {}
    for i=1, #table do
     table.insert(sumTable,table[i])
    end
    for i=1, #otherTable do
     table.insert(sumTable,otherTable[i])
    end
    return sumTable
end
}
setmetatable(table1,metatable)

table1 = table1 + table2
```

this error pops up after runnning the program

> lua: [string ""]:6: attempt to call field 'insert' (a nil value)
> stack traceback:
> [string ""]:6: in function <[string ""]:3>
> [string ""]:16: in main chunk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code for `__add` uses `table` as a parameter which is shadowing the `table` library. Rename the parameter to something else.